# using list comprehension how do i calculate how many digits there are in a list of characters

Tags: haskell

I need to calculate the number of digits that appear in a list of characters using list comprehension in Haskell.

so far i have found out how to do it using recursion but am struggling to use list comprehension:

e.g. in the following list `['1','2','3','4','2','a','s','d','f']`
the answer would be `5`

I have tried using recursion as well as higher order functions

List Comprehension:

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta = [ x | x <- length . filter isDigit]
```

Recursion:

```
countb :: [Char] -> Int
countb [] = 0
countb (x:xs)  
    | isDigit x = 1 + countb xs 
    | otherwise = countb xs
```

I call `countb ['1','2','3','4','2','a','s','d','f']` and the answer is `5`.

Comment: You probably mean `counta xs = length [ x | x <- xs, isDigit x]`.

Comment: I don't see why you *would* use a list comprehension to do this.

Comment: `counta = length . filter isDigit`.

Comment: Maybe use: `let ls = ['1','2','3','4','2','a','s','d','f']  in  length  $  [ x | x <- ls,  isDigit x ]`

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, as @AJFarmar has pointed out the correct answer.
Let the types guide your answer.

You need a function that takes a list and returns the number digits present (Int)
so the function should have the type as you have mentioned to be:

`counta :: [char] -> Int`

But your function definition for `counta` says that it is a List. Which is what the type checker might be complaining about as a List is not an Int. To use the list comprehension idiom you need to get the name of the list, lets say `xs`, so that you can iterate through each of its elements. And for each element in `xs` it also has to be a digit. You already have a function `isDigit` that does the work of telling you if a `char` is a digit.

Now you can have a list comprehension that tells you what exactly all those elements are:

`[x | x<-xs, isDigit x]`

And you need a count of all those elements, so pass it to the standard `length` function.

`counta = length [x | x<-xs , isDigit x]`

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt actually works as-is, if you just put `{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}` at the beginning of your program. However, it's super unidiomatic.

Your "list comprehension" is really a monad comprehension, since `length . filter isDigit` isn't a list but rather a function, and functions are monads. Also, any list or monad comprehension that's of the form `[x | x <- stuff]` is equivalent to just `stuff`. After that transformation, you wouldn't need to enable MonadComprehensions anymore, and then your solution would be idiomatic.

Alternatively, you could go even sillier, using the facts that `(.) = fmap` and `fmap f xs = [f x | x <- xs]`, and end up with this:

```
counta :: [Char] -> Int
counta = [length x | x <- filter isDigit]
```

Comment: ... or `Prelude> :set -XMonadComprehensions` at the GHCi prompt. (superbly done, seeing *that*. I didn't. :) )